# Getting error in basic bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a basic bash script to create a blank file each day that I can use for taking notes. I'm naming the file with the current date and then trying to write it into a notes directory under my Documents folder. Everything works fine if I use the complete path but I'd rather use ~ instead of typing out my home dir.

This works:

```
notesPath="/Users/erik/Documents/RN/_DailyNotes/"
```

And this fails with a "no such file or directory" error:

```
notesPath="~/Documents/RN/_DailyNotes/"
```

I'm doing the following after creating notesPath:

```
todayFile=$notesPath$fileName
todayPretty=$(date "+%m/%d/%y")
echo "Daily $todayPretty" >> $todayFile
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running this script via a cron job? It's probably not executing as your user, so `~` is not resolving to your home folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash does not expand `~` inside of quotes.  Try:

```
notesPath=~/"Documents/RN/_DailyNotes/"
```

For all the gory details on when and how `~` expands, see `man bash`, particularly the section entitled `Tilde Expansion`.